# Handling CloudKit Errors

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, cloudkit

I am looking for general advice on handling CloudKit errors in Swift and am having trouble finding good examples online. Here are the things I'm wondering:

1) Should I account for every single error type each time the possibility for an error arises, or is that not really necessary?

2) I have read that one common way of handling CloudKit errors is by retrying to execute the operation after the time interval the error message provides. Should this retry basically be my standard procedure for all errors?

3) Do different CloudKit operations (save, fetch, etc.) produce different types of errors, or is there one standard set of CloudKit errors?

Thanks in advance! I'm just looking for general info on how to go about tackling error handling with CloudKit because I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you want to check every cloudkit call for errors. Apple stresses this point in the cloudkit-related WWDC videos.

What you do when you detect an error varies greatly. Retry is sometimes an option, but sometimes not appropriate. If you're using batch operations, retrying may require some additional work to extract the just the records that failed. So, yes you may sometimes want to retry, but no, you probably won't automatically retry every operation that fails.

There is one set of errors, defined in `CKError.h`. But, you don't always just get a CKError. Sometimes, especially with `CKErrorPartialFailure`, you get a top-level error that contains nested errors that you also have to unwrap. As of IOS 10, the list of errors in `CKError.h` looks like:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CKErrorCode) {
    CKErrorInternalError                  = 1,  /* CloudKit.framework encountered an error.  This is a non-recoverable error. */
    CKErrorPartialFailure                 = 2,  /* Some items failed, but the operation succeeded overall. Check CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey in the userInfo dictionary for more details. */
    CKErrorNetworkUnavailable             = 3,  /* Network not available */
    CKErrorNetworkFailure                 = 4,  /* Network error (available but CFNetwork gave us an error) */
    CKErrorBadContainer                   = 5,  /* Un-provisioned or unauthorized container. Try provisioning the container before retrying the operation. */
    CKErrorServiceUnavailable             = 6,  /* Service unavailable */
    CKErrorRequestRateLimited             = 7,  /* Client is being rate limited */
    CKErrorMissingEntitlement             = 8,  /* Missing entitlement */
    CKErrorNotAuthenticated               = 9,  /* Not authenticated (writing without being logged in, no user record) */
    CKErrorPermissionFailure              = 10, /* Access failure (save, fetch, or shareAccept) */
    CKErrorUnknownItem                    = 11, /* Record does not exist */
    CKErrorInvalidArguments               = 12, /* Bad client request (bad record graph, malformed predicate) */
    CKErrorResultsTruncated NS_DEPRECATED(10_10, 10_12, 8_0, 10_0, "Will not be returned") = 13,
    CKErrorServerRecordChanged            = 14, /* The record was rejected because the version on the server was different */
    CKErrorServerRejectedRequest          = 15, /* The server rejected this request.  This is a non-recoverable error */
    CKErrorAssetFileNotFound              = 16, /* Asset file was not found */
    CKErrorAssetFileModified              = 17, /* Asset file content was modified while being saved */
    CKErrorIncompatibleVersion            = 18, /* App version is less than the minimum allowed version */
    CKErrorConstraintViolation            = 19, /* The server rejected the request because there was a conflict with a unique field. */
    CKErrorOperationCancelled             = 20, /* A CKOperation was explicitly cancelled */
    CKErrorChangeTokenExpired             = 21, /* The previousServerChangeToken value is too old and the client must re-sync from scratch */
    CKErrorBatchRequestFailed             = 22, /* One of the items in this batch operation failed in a zone with atomic updates, so the entire batch was rejected. */
    CKErrorZoneBusy                       = 23, /* The server is too busy to handle this zone operation. Try the operation again in a few seconds. */
    CKErrorBadDatabase                    = 24, /* Operation could not be completed on the given database. Likely caused by attempting to modify zones in the public database. */
    CKErrorQuotaExceeded                  = 25, /* Saving a record would exceed quota */
    CKErrorZoneNotFound                   = 26, /* The specified zone does not exist on the server */
    CKErrorLimitExceeded                  = 27, /* The request to the server was too large. Retry this request as a smaller batch. */
    CKErrorUserDeletedZone                = 28, /* The user deleted this zone through the settings UI. Your client should either remove its local data or prompt the user before attempting to re-upload any data to this zone. */
    CKErrorTooManyParticipants            NS_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0) = 29, /* A share cannot be saved because there are too many participants attached to the share */
    CKErrorAlreadyShared                  NS_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0) = 30, /* A record/share cannot be saved, doing so would cause a hierarchy of records to exist in multiple shares */
    CKErrorReferenceViolation             NS_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0) = 31, /* The target of a record's parent or share reference was not found */
    CKErrorManagedAccountRestricted       NS_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0) = 32, /* Request was rejected due to a managed account restriction */
    CKErrorParticipantMayNeedVerification NS_AVAILABLE(10_12, 10_0) = 33, /* Share Metadata cannot be determined, because the user is not a member of the share.  There are invited participants on the share with email addresses or phone numbers not associated with any iCloud account. The user may be able to join the share if they can associate one of those email addresses or phone numbers with their iCloud account via the system Share Accept UI. Call UIApplication's openURL on this share URL to have the user attempt to verify their information. */
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
```

One approach, while you're developing and testing the app, is to check every cloudkit operation for an error, and if detected, fire an NSAssert to stop the app. Then, examine the error, underlying errors and context to determine why it failed and what you need to do about it. Most likely, over time, you'll see common patterns emerge and you can then consider building a generic error handler.

Answer (score 9):

I've written a CloudKit help that makes it much easier to process errors. This is just a starting point and there is a lot more that can be done.

The main focus of this helper, in its current state, is to make it easy to retry errors that should be retried after an appropriate timeout.

But you still need to deal with errors that shouldn't be retried such as the user's iCloud storage being full. Even with this helper, every call to one of these helper methods needs to properly handle the result and possibly report an error to the user. Of course you can add a help method that checks all of the possible error types and shows an appropriate message. Then all uses of the CloudKit code can call that one helper method.

This also only covers a few of the possible operations. You would want to add support for other operations as well. Lastly, this doesn't handle partial errors yet. That would be another useful enhancement.

```
import Foundation
import CloudKit

public class CloudKitHelper {
    private static func determineRetry(error: Error) -> Double? {
        if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
            switch ckerror {
            case CKError.requestRateLimited, CKError.serviceUnavailable, CKError.zoneBusy, CKError.networkFailure:
                let retry = ckerror.retryAfterSeconds ?? 3.0

                return retry
            default:
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            if nserror.domain == NSCocoaErrorDomain {
                if nserror.code == 4097 {
                    print("cloudd is dead")

                    return 6.0
                }
            }

            print("Unexpected error: \(error)")
        }

        return nil
    }

    public static func modifyRecordZonesOperation(database: CKDatabase, recordZonesToSave: [CKRecordZone]?, recordZoneIDsToDelete: [CKRecordZoneID]?, modifyRecordZonesCompletionBlock: @escaping (([CKRecordZone]?, [CKRecordZoneID]?, Error?) -> Void)) {
        let op = CKModifyRecordZonesOperation(recordZonesToSave: recordZonesToSave, recordZoneIDsToDelete: recordZoneIDsToDelete)
        op.modifyRecordZonesCompletionBlock = { (savedRecordZones: [CKRecordZone]?, deletedRecordZoneIDs: [CKRecordZoneID]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                if let delay = determineRetry(error: error) {
                    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                        CloudKitHelper.modifyRecordZonesOperation(database: database, recordZonesToSave: recordZonesToSave, recordZoneIDsToDelete: recordZoneIDsToDelete, modifyRecordZonesCompletionBlock: modifyRecordZonesCompletionBlock)
                    }
                } else {
                    modifyRecordZonesCompletionBlock(savedRecordZones, deletedRecordZoneIDs, error)
                }
            } else {
                modifyRecordZonesCompletionBlock(savedRecordZones, deletedRecordZoneIDs, error)
            }
        }
        database.add(op)
    }

    public static func modifyRecords(database: CKDatabase, records: [CKRecord], completion: @escaping (([CKRecord]?, Error?) -> Void)) {
        CloudKitHelper.modifyAndDeleteRecords(database: database, records: records, recordIDs: nil) { (savedRecords, deletedRecords, error) in
            completion(savedRecords, error)
        }
    }

    public static func deleteRecords(database: CKDatabase, recordIDs: [CKRecordID], completion: @escaping (([CKRecordID]?, Error?) -> Void)) {
        CloudKitHelper.modifyAndDeleteRecords(database: database, records: nil, recordIDs: recordIDs) { (savedRecords, deletedRecords, error) in
            completion(deletedRecords, error)
        }
    }

    public static func modifyAndDeleteRecords(database: CKDatabase, records: [CKRecord]?, recordIDs: [CKRecordID]?, completion: @escaping (([CKRecord]?, [CKRecordID]?, Error?) -> Void)) {
        let op = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: records, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDs)
        op.savePolicy = .allKeys
        op.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (savedRecords: [CKRecord]?, deletedRecordIDs: [CKRecordID]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                if let delay = determineRetry(error: error) {
                    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                        CloudKitHelper.modifyAndDeleteRecords(database: database, records: records, recordIDs: recordIDs, completion: completion)
                    }
                } else {
                    completion(savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error)
                }
            } else {
                completion(savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error)
            }
        }
        database.add(op)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're the only resource that I found who explained how to handle "error" coming back from CloudKit.  i.e. "error as? CKError".  I thought it was casted already. Silly me.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. For Xamarin.IOS users, you can do `CKErrorCode error = (CKErrorCode)(int)(err.Code)` then you can do a switch statement on error variable.